# Converting floats to ints in an array

Tags: python

I have an array with as shape (0,5).
The content is `[[4.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 5.0]]`

How can I convert it into `[[4 3 0 1 5]]`?

Comment: I think it will not necessary to do that because when I have an array a = [[1. 2. 5. 6. 7.]] and an array b = [3 2 7 8 9] and i write code like if a[0,1] == b[1] the compiler assumes 2. is equal 2. So I do not need to convert the 1. 2. 5. etc into 1 2 5 ?

Answer (score 2):

A simple list comprehension can do this.

```
a = [[4.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 5.0]]
b = [[int(x) for x in a[0]]]
```

We are asking Python to convert each element of the list `a[0]` into an `int`. Look up [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more info on how it works and how to do it yourself in the future.